# How to explode the dataframe which has String schema using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in `df1` and when i execute `df1.printSchema()` i see:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- special_values: string (nullable = true)
```

The `special_values` are in array form but its showing in `string` form. I need to explode the `special_values` data.

```
+----+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name|last_name|special_values                                                                               |
+----+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|A   |B        |[{name=address, value=some address}, {name=city, value=Chd}, {name=zip_code, value=160036}]  |
|X   |Y        |[{name=address, value=some address}, {name=city, value=Dallas}, {name=zip_code, value=02431}]|
+----+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`Explode()` function didn't worked since it is `string`.What i tried is :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
user_schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("value", StringType(), True)
    ])
)

df2 = (df1.withColumn("special_value", F.from_json("special_values", user_schema))
       .selectExpr("inline(special_value)", "last_name")
       )
```

I tried to execute:

```
df2.show()
```

I see the empty dataframe.

```
+----+-----+---------+
|name|value|last_name|
+----+-----+---------+
+----+-----+---------+
```

what's the issue here?
My source data is:

```
# JSON data
data = {
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "last_name": "B",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "value": "some address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Chd"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "160036"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "X",
            "last_name": "Y",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "value": "some address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Dallas"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "02431"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using azure synapse, databricks?

Comment: no normal notebook

Comment: json format does not look right, try to run the json through a json formatter to check the format.

Comment: @HimadriPal i have put the original source data i think it is correct and i have used df_flattened = df.select(
    explode("records").alias("record")
) this to explode the data

Comment: I just created a dataframe and it is showing correct schema and special_values are treated as array. Which spark version you are using?

Comment: Are you sure you’re using spark.read.json() to read the json file?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use the `explode` method on the `records` object of the `data` variable that you shared. You should be able to create a dataframe with the columns as the keys (`name` & `value`) from the `special_values` array element.

```py
# JSON data
data = """
{
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "last_name": "B",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "value": "some address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Chd"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "160036"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "X",
            "last_name": "Y",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "value": "some address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Dallas"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "02431"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""

# Read the JSON data into a DataFrame
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([data]))

# Flatten the records array
df = df.select(explode(df.records).alias("records"))

# Flatten the special_values array
df = df.select("records.name", "records.last_name", explode(df.records.special_values).alias("special_values"))

# Select the individual elements of the special_values struct
df = df.selectExpr("name", "last_name", "special_values.name as special_values_name", "special_values.value as special_values_value")

df.show(df.count(), truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WITH input_cte AS (
    SELECT
        INLINE(            
            FROM_JSON(
                input,
                'records array<struct<name:string, last_name:string, special_values: array<struct<name:string, value:string>>>>'
            ).records
        )
    FROM VALUES ('{ "records": [ { "name": "A", "last_name": "B", "special_values": [ { "name": "address", "value": "some address" }, { "name": "city", "value": "Chd" }, { "name": "zip_code", "value": "160036" } ] }, { "name": "X", "last_name": "Y", "special_values": [ { "name": "address", "value": "some address" }, { "name": "city", "value": "Dallas" }, { "name": "zip_code", "value": "02431" } ] } ] }')
    AS (input)
)
SELECT 
    name,
    last_name,
    INLINE(special_values)
FROM input_cte
```

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|name|last_name|name    |value       |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|A   |B        |address |some address|
|A   |B        |city    |Chd         |
|A   |B        |zip_code|160036      |
|X   |Y        |address |some address|
|X   |Y        |city    |Dallas      |
|X   |Y        |zip_code|02431       |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
```